# Why use many columns in GROUP BY and HAVING clause in these examples

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the schema [here](https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial-ER.pdf) I'm trying to understand and solve the below 3 sql queries as I'm confused:

1- Present a table giving the names of the countries with ≥ 50% urbanization
rates, their urbanization rates, and their per capita GDP. Note that
urbanization rate is the percentage of population living in cities. Do not
count cities with NULL values for population.

```
SELECT country.name, round(sum(city.population)/country.population, 3) AS urban, round(gdp/country.population, 3) AS gdppc 
FROM city 
INNER JOIN country ON code = country 
INNER JOIN economy ON code = economy.country 
WHERE city.population IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY country.name, country.population, economy.gdp 
HAVING round(sum(city.population)/country.population, 3) >= 0.5 
ORDER BY urban DESC;
```

**In the above query, Why I need to include `country.population` and `economy.gdp`  in the `GROUP BY`? If I tried using just `country.name` in the `GROUP BY` I get an error saying I should include the others.**

2- Show organizations that have as members all the European countries with over 50 million people?

```
SELECT name 
FROM organization 
INNER JOIN (SELECT organization
            FROM country 
            INNER JOIN encompasses 
            ON code = encompasses.country 
            INNER JOIN ismember 
            ON code = ismember.country 
            WHERE population > 50000000 AND continent = 'Europe' 
            GROUP BY organization 
            HAVING count(ismember.country) = (SELECT count(*) 
                                              FROM country 
                                              INNER JOIN encompasses 
                                              ON code = country 
                                              WHERE population > 50000000 AND continent = 'Europe')) 
            AS innerQuery 
            ON abbreviation = innerQuery.organization;
```

**Why I need the HAVING Part above?**

3- Insert a new organization called “Tivoli” and a trigger that says if Germany joins “Tivoli” then so too must the UK and France. Insert Germany into the “Tivoli” organization. Confirm proper behavior.

I tried the below script but it's not working, any advice please?

```
do $$
begin
IF(NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM organization WHERE organization."name" = 'Tivoli' AND organization.country = 'D' ))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO organization VALUES ('Tivoli','Tivoli organization',NULL,'F',NULL,NULL);
        INSERT INTO organization VALUES ('Tivoli','Tivoli organization',NULL,'GB',NULL,NULL);

END;
end $$
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

You used country.population and economy.gdp in the select, outside of aggregate functions ( COUNT(), AVG() and SUM() ), and you have a GROUP BY. Everything that you select has to be in GROUP BY or inside of aggregate functions.

2)

Because you were asked to show organizations that have ALL of 50mil + people countries. With HAVING, you check if that organization has the right amount of countries.

3)

organization."name" = 'Tivoli' 
It's supposed to be :
organization.name

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should limit a question to one only, not 3. But here are some pointers for all 3:

> In the above query, Why I need to include `country.population` and `economy.gdp` in the `GROUP BY`? If I tried using just `country.name` in the GROUP BY I get an error saying I should include the others.

This is a requirement. A group by `country.name` alone would work (in Postgres 9.1+) only if the other two fields are known to be functionally dependent on `country.name`. But probably `country.name` is not the primary key of the `country` table, so in theory it is possible to have two records in that table with the same name, but different population.

The rule is [as follows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> When `GROUP BY` is present, it is not valid for the `SELECT` list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions **or if the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns**, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. **A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.**

This is implemented since version 9.1.

> Why I need the HAVING Part above?

Because a condition on an aggregate (`count` in this case) can only be performed after grouping, and can thus not be expressed in the `where` clause. In this case the `having` clause makes sure that the organisation is not only present in *some* big EU Member States, but *all* big EU Member states.

> I tried the below script but it's not working, any advice please?

Without a proper database schema, it is not possible to provide you with the correct SQ, but from the ERD diagram it seems that the `organization` table does not have a `country` field. Instead the `ismember` table connects organizations with countries. You would only insert one `organization`, but several `ismember` records (one per Member State involved)

It is better also to name the fields in your `insert` statement, so it is clear which value corresponds to which field.